# Stuck. I need some VBA code to insert double-quotes around strings in each cell in an excel range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm familiar with VB.NET, but VBA in excel has me stumped.
With my best attempt, I get a "Type mismatch" error:

```
Sub AddQuotes()

    For Each x In Range("List").Cells
    x.Text = "*" * " & x.text & " & "*"
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That code should read:

For Each x In Range("List").Cells
 
x.Text = "*" * " & x.text & " & "*" 

Next

Comment: In VB.NET, string concatenation is performed in exactly same way as in VBA. Same is true for escaping double quotes. Therefore, the correct code, `"""" & x.value & """"`, would be obvious for a person familiar with VB.NET.

Answer (score 12):

Try using chr(34) for the double-quote character

eg chr(34) & x.text & chr(34)